# What is this flag in the gutter of my Visual Studio code editor? How do I get rid of it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In VS2017, I was trying to use a shortcut key combination from an older version. (Naturally, it doesn't work because MS has to change things all time - but enough of that rant...)

Instead, this flag appears.  In the left margin.

[image]

When I tried that key combination, or a variant of it, again, I just kept getting MORE of them.  The cursor jumps to new places and adds them. No way to get rid of them!

They appear to line up with the scroll bar on the right. But it does nothing that I can determine except clutter the UI.

[image]

No clue as to what it is.  Hovering over it doesn't say anything. Right clicks don't tell me anything. Web searches yield nothing about what this is, what it means, why it's there...

How do I get rid of it?

I'm less interested in what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bookmark. You can use them to easily jump between sections of code that  you have marked "useful" for the problem you're currently trying to solve:

You can toggle, navigate between and **clear bookmarks** from the <kbd>Edit</kbd> - <kbd>Bookmarks</kbd> menu:

[image: Bookmark menu]